# Uploading an Excel File to a SharePoint Folder or Site using Power Automate Desktop and send an e-mail

Tags: excel, instance, power-automate, power-automate-desktop

I am trying to Upload an Excel File to a SharePoint Folder or Site using Power Automate Desktop.

But every time I try to upload it, the file uploads to the folder as an excel instance with the name "excel instance" instead of a variable I set before in my flow.

I can't find an option that allows me to convert the excel instance to an excel file and don't know if it even possible.

I have the Premium version, so if it helps, I can connect the flow with the cloud version of Power Automate

I tried the following steps.

1. Setting the local file path as a variable [see img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWhgn.png),
2. Converting the file to binary data (because the step - Create file - requires a file in Binary data format for "File Contents") [see img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfWuu.png),
3. Creating the SharePoint File [see img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Tj3y.png),
4. Creating the link to the file using the Item id from step 3 [see img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jshTa.png),
5. sending the e-mail with the link [see img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbmMy.png).

[See steps here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3NcW.png)

I expected this to just upload an excel file to sharepoint but it uploads an "excel instance"
[[image: see img1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, **found the answer**.

It wasn't uploading an excel instance, but it was uploading a file without an extension.

**Why?** Because when I uploaded the file, I was uploading just binary data, I did not specify and/or give instructions to the program to convert the binary data to a different file type.

It was weird because I defined a variable beforehand that contained the extension.

To fix this **I added the right extension to the "file name"** in the Create File action(in my case .xlsm).